# MYSQL group by month but not on first day of month

Tags: mysql, sql

My table votes contains votes that have been made by users at different times:

```
id  item_id position    user_id created_at
1   2   0   1   11/21/2013 11:27
26  1   1   1   11/21/2013 11:27
27  3   2   1   11/21/2013 11:27
42  2   2   1   12/7/2013 2:20
41  3   1   1   12/7/2013 2:20
40  1   0   1   12/7/2013 2:20
67  2   2   1   12/13/2013 1:13
68  1   1   1   12/13/2013 1:13
69  3   0   1   12/13/2013 1:13
84  2   0   1   12/28/2013 2:29
83  3   2   1   12/28/2013 2:29
82  1   1   1   12/28/2013 2:29
113 3   0   1   1/17/2014 22:08
114 1   1   1   1/17/2014 22:08
115 2   2   1   1/17/2014 22:08
138 2   0   1   1/20/2014 16:49
139 1   1   1   1/20/2014 16:49
140 3   2   1   1/20/2014 16:49
141 1   1   11  1/20/2014 16:51
142 3   2   11  1/20/2014 16:51
143 2   0   11  1/20/2014 16:51
```

I need to tally the results on a monthly basis but here's the tricky part: the start/end of the month does not necessarily fall on the first day of the month.  So if the votes are due on the 10th day of every month, I need a vote that was cast on the 10th to be in a different group from a vote that was cast on the 11th.  Using the data above, I want to get three groups:

Group 1: 6 votes (11/21 and 12/7)
Group 2: 6 votes (12/13, 12/28)
Group 3: 9 votes (1/17, 1/20)

I've tried a lot of approaches but to no avail.  This is my query right now:

```
select created_at, ADDDATE(DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-01'),interval 10 day) as duedate,count("id") from votes where list_id = 2 group by duedate
```

I am getting group sizes of 3, 9, and 9, not 6, 6 and 9.  Any help you can provide would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is close.  You just need to subtract 9 days (10 - 1) from the current day to get the month:

```
select created_at, date_sub(created_at, interval 9 day) as duedate,
       count(id)
from votes
where list_id = 2
group by duedate;
```

`date_format()` converts a date to a string.  There is no need to convert a date value to a character value for this query.

EDIT:

To group by month:

```
select date_format(date_sub(created_at, interval 9 day), '%Y-%m') as YYYYMM,
       count(id)
from votes
where list_id = 2
group by YYYYMM;
```

Comment: No, this just adjusts the duedate for each vote; I need to group the votes. So all votes between January 10 and February 10 will be grouped together.

Comment: @MikeC . . . See the edit.  I was basing the answer too much on your query.